# ValueError when executing os.popen(...)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, operating-system, system

I want to get the width of a terminal, to print a certain elemnt till the end of the line. But I get an ValueError, when executing this command in Windows:

```
rows, columns = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

In Ubuntu, this is working perfectly, but not in Windows.
What can I do there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below lines to get buffer size in windows command prompt

```
rows = int(os.popen('mode con | findstr Lines','r').read().strip('\n').strip(' ').split(':')[1].strip(' '))
columns = int(os.popen('mode con | findstr Columns','r').read().strip('\n').strip(' ').split(':')[1].strip(' '))
```

Comment: When I try this, I get `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: can you share the code you are using because these statements are working fine for me independently